# Switch between 640x480 and 640x360 resolution in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, webcam

im using OpenCV 4.3 with c++ and the VideoCapture to get the videostream from a Logitech C922 Pro Webcam.

Im changing the resolution with

```
cap.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,height)
cap.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,width)
```

This works fine until im using either the resolution of 640x480 or 640x360. In this cases OpenCV stays in the aspect ratio it was before (640x480 on startup).

Is there an efficitent way to change the resolution to the right one instead of changing it to another one before?

Answer (score 0):

`CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT` or `CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH` are used to switch the resolution of your camera. If your camera doesn't support that resolution you set, the code will not work.  If you check the [specs of Logitech C922](https://www.logitech.com/en-roeu/product/c922-pro-stream-webcam#specification-tabular), you will see that it doesn't include the resolutions you desired.

There are other options you can apply:

1- You can crop the desired sizes(ex. 640,360) from the main frame.

2- You can [resize](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d) the frame but this will crash the aspect ratio.

Comment: I can only find the "max resolution" with 1080/30 or 720/60. And as I wrote, it is possible to set the desired resolution but with the detour over another one. In addition I can set many other resolutions with these commands.